# Error while Passing function pointer as parameter

Tags: c, pointers, shared-libraries, function-pointers

I have a program which will call a function present in a library. The arguments of the function is a function pointer.

Helloworld.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "helloworld.h"

struct data_buffer
   {
        char name[10];
   }data;

int main()
  {
     int result; 

     int (*func_pointer)(&data_buffer); //function pointer which takes structure as parameter

      result=send_data(func_ponter); //error

      func_pointer(&data_buffer);  //call the SPI write

  }
```

helloworld.h

```
#ifndef HELLOWORLD_H
#define HELLOWORLD_H

/* Some cross-platform definitions generated by autotools */
#if HAVE_CONFIG_H
#  include <config.h>
#endif /* HAVE_CONFIG_H */
/*
 * Example function
 */

struct data_buffer;

extern int send_data(int (*func_pointer)(&data_buffer)); //is the declaration correct

#endif
```

libexample.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int send_data(int (*func_pointer)(&data_buffer)) //error 
{

func_pointer=spi_write();  // assigning the function pointer to SPI WRITE function
return;
}
```

so my aim of the project is to send a function pointer as the parameter to  send_data function. in the library program the function pointer must be assigned to spi_write() function and then the SPI_Write can be called with the help of function pointer in the  Helloworld program.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve. What would assigning `spi_write` to the parameter accomplish? What *is* `spi_write`? (Also, when you write `x = y;`, you're "assigning y to x", not the other way around.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extern int send_data(int (*func_pointer)(&data_buffer)); //is the declaration correct
```

The parameter of a function must be a type. Types use `*` to indicate that it is a pointer. So `&data_buffer` is incorrect in a declaration.

Also note that in C, unlike C++, a struct name is not a type, you need to combine it with the keyword `struct` (or use a typedef). So use:

```
extern int send_data(int (*func_pointer)(struct data_buffer *));
```